# The size of unions of some families of sets

Tags: combinatorics, probability-distributions, generating-functions, simplicial-complex

Consider the class $\mathcal{F}_n^m$ of families of sets consisting of $n$ sets $s_i \subset \{1,2,\dots,n\cdot m\}$ of size $m$. For a family of sets $F \in \mathcal{F}_n^m$, $F = \{s_1,\dots,s_n\}$ with $|s_i| = m$, the size $\Sigma(F)$ of its union $\bigcup_{i=1,\dots,n} s_i$ is some number of which the  upper bound $\Sigma_{\textsf{max}}^{(nm)} = n\cdot m$ and the lower bound $\Sigma_{\textsf{min}}^{(nm)} = \min\{s\ |\  {s\choose m}\geq n\}$ are known.

I experimentally found out, that for $\mathcal{F}_4^4$, i.e. for 4-element sets of 4-element sets, the expected number $\Sigma_{\textsf{exp}}^{(44)}$ is approx. 10.936 and the sharp lower bound $\Sigma_{\textsf{min}}^{(44)}$ is 5. Furthermore I got this distribution of union sizes for some 10 million random samples taken from the universal set $\{1,2,\dots,16\}$.

[image]

My questions are:

- By which combinatorial considerations can the expected number $\Sigma_{\textsf{exp}}^{(nm)}$ of the union size for families of sets in $\mathcal{F}_n^m$ be calculated, giving 10.936 for the case $n=m=4$?
- What kind of distribution is the one I observed? It's obviously not a binomial distribution (because it's asymmetric), but it might be a Poisson distribution? How would I prove or check this?

Comment: What is the universal set of which your sets $s_i$ are subsets? Equivalently, from what distribution are you drawing your “random samples”? It seems like that matters. For families of four $4$-element sets of integers in $\{1,2,3,4\}$, the union always has exactly $4$ elements, but for families of four $4$-element sets of integers in $\{1,2,3,\dots 1000000\}$, it seems like the union typically has $16$ elements (non-empty intersections would be rare). I might be missing something, because I don’t understand where your lower bound comes from.

Comment: @SteveKass: Of course, you are right, I should have made it explicit. I have now done so.

Comment: Your question is related to a variation of the coupon collector problem. Suppose there are $m\cdot n$ coupons, and a collector buys $n$ $m$-packs of coupons. (An $m$-pack of coupons is a randomly-selected set of $m$ distinct coupons.) What is the distribution of the number of distinct coupons obtained, and what is the expected value? Problems like this are well-studied, so maybe you can find something in print. For example, section 4 of this paper is close: https://mat.uab.cat/matmat_antiga/PDFv2014/v2014n02.pdf

Comment: You made my day!

Answer (score 1):

For the first question. The probability that you pick a configuration is given by
$$\frac{4!}{\binom{16}{4}^4},$$
Then to compute the expected value you need
$$P(|\Sigma|=k)=\frac{4!\binom{16}{k}}{\binom{16}{4}^4}\sum _{i=0}^k\frac{(-1)^i}{4!}\binom{k}{i}\binom{k-i}{4}^4=\frac{\binom{16}{k}}{\binom{16}{4}^4}\sum _{i=0}^k(-1)^i\binom{k}{i}\binom{k-i}{4}^4,$$
this because you pick the elements in the union in $\binom{16}{k}$ ways and then you need to use them all, so inclusion-exclusion gives you the other expression. If you do $$\mathbb{E}[|\Sigma|]=\sum _{i=0}^{16}k\cdot P(|\Sigma|=k)=10.9375,$$
you get the number you said.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you think it's a routine procedure to show the equivalence of your expression and the simple one given by user md5 in the other answer?

Comment: You are welcome. I would say that it is possible, but the fourth power scares me a little bit to try it. Either trying to use $\binom{a}{b}\binom{b}{c}=\binom{a}{c}\binom{a-c}{b-c}$ or using the probability generating function should work after some work.

Comment: Can one simply replace 16 by nm and the two 4s by n and m (which by which?) to get the general formula? Or does it hold for n=m=4 only?

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker You can simply replace. The exponents are $n$'s and in the binomial there are m's.

Answer (score 1):

For an element $x\in[nm]$, the probability that $x$ is *not* picked in a random set $S\subseteq [nm]$ of size $m$ is $\frac{nm-m}{nm}=1-1/n$. Therefore by independence, for a random collection of $n$ such sets, the probability that $x$ is *not* in their union is $(1-1/n)^n$. By linearity of expectation,

$$\Sigma_{\text{exp}}^{n,m}=\left(1-\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right)nm.$$

I do not think the distribution is a standard one, but you can probably obtain additional information about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you think it's a routine procedure to show the equivalence of your expression and the more complicated one given by user Phicar in the other answer?

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker - definitely a painful procedure. As long as you only need the expectation, I would not recommend going through the computation of the probability mass for such combinatorial problems.

Comment: But it would be enlightening: Such a complicated expression like Phicar's one collapses to such a simple one like yours?

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker - to be honest, I usually don't find such combinatorial proofs very enlightening. Computers are probably better with symbolic computations. ;)